# how to make the all the elements fix according to their height in tableview

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I tried to add buttons, textboxes and text to tableview. I want the row height to get adjusted automatically according to the height of each ui component. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the specific height for each cell in the UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

It would be best, if you find a way how to calculate the height of your cells dynamically.